# Backcolor only last row UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdk

My UITableView shows variable data from a SOAP web service. The last row shows totals. How can I give **only** the last row in the TableView a grey background?

This is what I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    NSString *basis = [chunks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *words2 = [basis componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    for (NSString *word2 in words2) {
        [chunks2 addObject:word2];
    }

    NSString *artikelnaamfull = @" ";
    if ([words2 count] > 2) artikelnaamfull = [words2 objectAtIndex:2];

    NSString *aantal = @" ";
    if ([words2 count] > 2) aantal = [words2 objectAtIndex:6];

    NSString *prijsex = @" ";
    if ([words2 count] > 2) prijsex = [words2 objectAtIndex:7];

    NSString *artikelnaam = [artikelnaamfull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Omschr =" withString:@""];

    if ([artikelnaamfull isEqualToString:@" "]) {


        artikelnaam = [words2 objectAtIndex:0];
        artikelnaam = [artikelnaam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Totalex= " withString:@"Totaal excl. BTW: € "];
        artikelnaam = [artikelnaam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Totalin= " withString:@"Totaal incl. BTW: € "];


        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = artikelnaam;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";

    } else {

    aantal = [aantal stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Aantal=" withString:@""];
    prijsex = [prijsex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Exclusief=" withString:@""];
    prijsex = [prijsex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];


    double value = [prijsex doubleValue];
    int value2 = [aantal doubleValue];

    double totaal = value2 * value;

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSString *totaal2 = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:totaal]];

        cell.textLabel.text = artikelnaam;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ verkocht x € %.2f € %@",aantal,value,totaal2];

    }


    return cell;
}
```

What must I add or change to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Simply set the cell's `backgroundColor` in the `tableView:willDisplayRowAtIndexPath:` method. Be sure to set the background color for ALL cells so you don't see weird results as the table scrolls.

Answer (score 3):

In your `cellForIndexPath` method:

```
if (indexPath.row == [tableview numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) {
    // set some last row background color
} else {
    // set background color for every other row
}
```

Comment: Put this ANYWHERE in your code after you've instantiated the `cell` object.

Comment: When I scroll, other rows will be also with background. How to fix this?

Comment: In the `else`.  In the `if` set the last row's color.  In the `if` set the non-last row color.